# How can I programmatically override the title tag from within custom module?

Tags: 7

I have a custom module that creates a search form and displays search results. We have a need where we want the title that displays in the browser tab to change depending on the search criteria. This particular search searches jobs that are available in specific specialties. I know you can use drupal_set_title() to change the title that gets displayed to the user in the H1 tag on the page, but what I am talking about is changing the title in the browser. The actual title tag for SEO purposes. So by default, the Browser tab title says "Job Search | My Site Here" ("My Site Here" is a place holder for the actual name of my site). When they perform a search we want the title to change to "{Specialty Name} Jobs | My Site Here". So for example if they search on the specialty "Cardiology", the browser title will be "Cardiology Jobs | My Site Here". I know there are custom modules to handle changing the page title dynamically, but those are for existing content types. This job search has been created completely from within a custom module, so ALL of the pages are dynamic. Is there a way to edit the browser page title independently of the drupal_set_title() function from within the custom module?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question and answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/window-title-vs-page-title). In short, I think your might be looking for something like `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['head_title'] = t("The new HTML title.");
}
```